# How to record datareader results at Session?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

How to record datareader results at Session? I read database then value that I read want to assigne at Session

```
dr = islem.KayitGetir_DataReader("SELECT * FROM products P INNER JOIN products_description PD ON P.products_id = PD.products_id WHERE P.products_id='" + Session[i].ToString() + "'");

if (dr.Read())
{
    cartProductImage.ImageUrl = dr["products_thumbnails_images"].ToString();
    lblCartProductName.Text   = dr["pro_description_name"].ToString();
    lblCartProductPrice.Text  = dr["products_price"].ToString();
    dr.Close();

    Session["ProImg"]      = cartProductImage;
    Session["ProImgName"]  = lblCartProductName;
    Session["ProImgPrice"] = lblCartProductPrice;
}
```

Comment: you might want to send the data from Data Access to somewhere you can access session. By creating a class maybe?

Comment: I have new problem now, I can't do to import mysql temporary table. baglanti.Open();
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO " + Session["TableName"].ToString() + " (products_thumbnails_images, pro_description_name, products_price) VALUES('" + cartProImg + "','" + cartProName + "','" + cartProPrice + "')";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
baglanti.Close();

Comment: what is the error, you need to pass the `tablename` as a parameter to your data access once you retrieve it from `Session`.

Comment: @Amit , thanks for your interest, I solved this problem that.

Comment: how did you solve it?